# Different boxes do different things

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get this script working, but I am having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()

lbl = Label(window.title("Work please"))

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

def clicked():
    import os
    os.system("start cmd.exe /k runas /user:domain\username cmd")
def clicked2():
    DO 2nd thing
def clicked3():    
    DO 3rd thing
    btn = Button(tab1, text="Do Stuff 1", command=clicked)
    btn.grid(column=1, row=1)
    btn = Button(tab1, text="Do Stuff 2", command=clicked2)
    btn.grid(column=2, row=2)
    btn = Button(tab1, text="Do Stuff 3", command=clicked3)
    btn.grid(column=3, row=3)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What errors are you getting if any? What is the expected outcome and what is actually happening? You example never calls any of your 3 functions. It appears that your buttons meant to call the functions are indented incorrectly.

Comment: I have moved the indents all around and nothing helps.. 
If I write it like this it works just fine, but all of the buttons do the same thing then.

Comment: This cannot possible be true. "all of the buttons do the same thing" . Each button uses a different command thus cannot be doing the same thing. 2nd In your example your buttons are not being created due to them being in the 3rd functions. Maybe in your main code this indention is not messed up like this but here we go off what you have shown us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons are indented into the 3rd function. So your buttons will never be made and thus cannot be used to call the 3 functions.

Fix:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os


def clicked():
    os.system("start cmd.exe /k runas /user:domain\username cmd")


def clicked2():
    print('DO 2nd thing')


def clicked3():
    print('DO 3rd thing')


window = tk.Tk()
lbl = tk.Label(window.title("Work please"))
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
tk.Button(tab1, text="Do Stuff 1", command=clicked).grid(column=1, row=1)
tk.Button(tab1, text="Do Stuff 2", command=clicked2).grid(column=2, row=2)
tk.Button(tab1, text="Do Stuff 3", command=clicked3).grid(column=3, row=3)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried to post the code that was working showing, the buttons all doing the same thing, but it site said it was too many characters..soo

Comment: Your answer fixed it though thank you!